# SDK lives in C:\windows\assembly on a remote machine how do I add this into VS?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk

I am using sharepoint based plugin that has an SDK, the SDK is installed as part of the plugin on the Sharepoint server, the SDK documentation mentions the assembly sharepoint.eplugin.dll, I couldn't find this file anywhere but I've been told everything I need is in the c:\windows\assembly folder, I've not come across this before and the files in here can't be copied out but I can see sharepoint.eplug in this folder, so my question is how do I reference these files from my desktop machine?

Many thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click add reference in your project in VS you will see .Net tab which should list your assemblies from GAC (c:\windows\assembly)

Comment: Hi, thanks but I only see items from my local PC, how would I access the GAC on another machine?

Comment: Why would you want to access the GAC on another machine? If you link to a signed assembly in your GAC, on the remote system the assembly will also be used from that system's GAC.

Comment: To have the plugin installed on my machine, I would have to install Sharepoint and SQL which may be what I need to do but I wondered if there was any easy way to connect to the remote machine and use that GAC.

Comment: You need to install it on your local system. You can not "connect" to "remote" GAC